How to sort mongo aggregation by month and year
I am trying to group, sum and sort data by date created in the format %m%Y.
The problem I am facing is that aggregation result is sorted by month only without year, so I get something like:
012024, 022024, 032024,042024,052024,062023,072023,082023
This desired order is:
062023,072023,082023,012024, 022024, 032024,042024,052024
Any suggestions will be appreciated
Here is my pipeline:
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where(STATUS).nin("NEW",CANCELLED,REJECTED).and(DATE_CREATED).gte(startDate)),
    project(sumField)
    .andExpression("toDate(" + expression + ")")
    .as("formattedDate"),
    project(sumField)
    .and("formattedDate")
    .dateAsFormattedString("%m%Y")
    .as(MONTH),
    group(MONTH).sum(sumField).as(SUM),
    project(SUM).and(MONTH).as(DESCRIPTION),
    project(SUM).and(DESCRIPTION).previousOperation(),
    sort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, DESCRIPTION))
);

AggregationResults<SumModel> results = mongoTemplate
.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, SumModel.class);
return results.getMappedResults();

The pojo is:
public class SumModel {
   private String description;
   private float sum;
   private float percentage;
}


That is the reason why you should store date fields as proper date objects. Meanwhile, you may use $dateFromParts to parse the field and continue working on it like this

@ray thanks for the suggestion. Using dateFromParts indeed solved the sorting issue. This however creates new date objects with day, time and time zone components. I will have to handle this some how. hanks again.

Not sure why creating date objects is a concern to you, but if you have autonomy on how the date is formed, you may consider a format similar to ISO format of %Y%m. This is also sortable.

Not a concern, just that we have about 30 microservices and is a big change. There were some historical reasons, which I don't remember now
